# Azure Web App created through Visual Studio doesnt show up in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, web-applications

I seem to have created an azure website in visual studio, but it doesn't come up in azure portal. I have verified the credentials used for azure against the credentials I am logging into with to Azure Portal. They are the same. I am able to hit the url of the site and it serves just fine.

[image: This is after I have created the site in visual studio]

[image: All items view of my dashboard, doesnt show the site]

Comment: Have you published anything to it? Have you tried to browse to it?

Comment: Yes I have published a sharepoint app into it, and when I browse it, it works just fine

Comment: Could it be so that you have several subscriptions and you are looking in the wrong one?

Comment: i have a *.onmicrosoft account, that I am using to sign in ( inside of VS as well as when I am looking to manage my webapps ) I doubt of there being a possibility of that happening.

Comment: @SwayamSiddha did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @eightx2 No i wasnt able to.